# How to compile LaTeX document from/with online sources?

Tags: compiling, online

Given any possible documentclass available, would it be possible to compile a document with sources that are stored online (e.g. in a cloud or server)?

If yes, would one need to use `\include{'http://<url to source>'}`?

If no, is it possible to implement such a feature?

I'm asking because some sources are too big to be stored on a local hard drive. This way it becomes easier to create a document with big data sources.

Google and site research didn't reveal anything useful.

Comment: Related to / possible duplicate of [Is it possible to input a file from the web](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249567/69818).

Comment: if the file is too big to put on your local drive you are going to need to run latex on a remote server rather than get the local tex to access the remote file