# Using listinputlisting to include a specific (git) commit

Tags: listings, external-files, shell-escape, lstlisting, git

I am discussing code which is in version control and would like to specify which version of the code to include.

I did some research and found packages like `gitlatex` and `gitinfo`, but though useful, they only work for the document itself
and of course `listings` itself.

I would prefer not to have copies of the file(s) in the document directory, but keep them in the git controlled directory.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use the [`\write18` approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20444/what-are-immediate-write18-and-how-does-one-use-them) to execute a git command that stores the specific file version in a temp file, and include it normally via `\lstinputlisting` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file can be included by using PDFLaTeXs `|` / shellescape feature 
(thanks [@siracusa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23765/siracusa) for pointing me to `\write18` ).

Reading command output is done by using `{|"script"}` for the file argument
[src](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249567/is-it-possible-to-input-a-file-from-the-web)

and these `"` can be replaced by using `\string"` to force compability with packages like `ngerman`[src](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/15887/was-ist-write18-oder-shell-escape).

A file having a specified commit can be checkedout (of a remote git repository) by using 
`git archive --remote=ssh://git@server/repo.git VERSION path/to/file` (here VERSION can be a TAG or a commithash or just master)[src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repositor).

To clean the output from the ssh connection we pipe the stderr to the trash by appending a `2>/dev/null`.

As `git archive` generates a tar archive, we have to remove the tar headers by using `tar` to read from stdin `-` and `--extract` it `--to-stdout`: `| tar --extract --file - --to-stdout` [src](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-Standard-Output.html).

**TL:DR**

for a remote file

```
\lstinputlisting{|\string"git archive --remote=ssh://git@server/repo.git VERSION path/to/file 2>/dev/null | tar --extract --file - --to-stdout\string"}
```

for a lokal file

```
\lstinputlisting{|\string"git archive --remote=/path/to/.git VERSION path/to/file 2>/dev/null | tar --extract --file - --to-stdout\string"}
```

Useful macro for this has been worked out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501640/shellescape-macro-nested-in-another-macro/501873#501873)