# shellescape macro nested in another macro

Tags: macros, listings, nesting, shell-escape

How do I use a shellescape (`| echo "stuff"`)  macro as another macros input if there are "bad" characters like `_` contained.

I will use my [full example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500463/using-listinputlisting-to-include-a-specific-git-commit) as reference.

The idea is to replace `\lstinputlisting{|\string"git archive --remote=ssh://git@server/repo.git VERSION path/to/file 2>/dev/null | tar --extract --file - --to-stdout\string"}`

with a macro like this

```
% set these so they can later be redefined
\providecommand{\GitRemote}{}
\providecommand{\GitIdentifier}{master}

\providecommand{\GitCheckout}[2][\GitIdentifier]{%
% #1 being the version/branch
% #2 being the file
| \string"git archive --remote=\GitRemote #1 \detokenize{#2} 2>/dev/null | tar --extract --file - --to-stdout \string"%
}
```

with usage
`\lstinputlisting{\GitCheckout{path_to_file.py}}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\providecommand{\GitRemote}{}
\providecommand{\GitIdentifier}{master}
\providecommand{\GitCheckout}[2][\GitIdentifier]{%
% #1 being the version/branch
% #2 being the file
| \string"git archive --remote=\GitRemote #1 \detokenize{#2} 2>/dev/null | tar --extract --file - --to-stdout \string"%
}
\begin{document}
renewcommand{\GitRemote}{ssh://git@trac.sagemath.org/sage.git}
\lstinputlisting{\GitCheckout{src/sage/coding/goppa.py}}
\end{document}
```

but i keep getting errors like this

`mwe.tex|10 error| Use of \\GitCheckout doesn't match its definition.`

so it seems there is some escaping going on (`\` to `\\`)

Comment: you have defined `\GitCheckout` to take an optional argument which means that it does not work by expansion, and the argument to `lstinputlisting` must _expand_ to a filename.

Comment: It's not clear why using `\providecommand`. Anyway, if you use `xparse`, then you can try `\NewDocumentCommand{\GitCheckout}{O{\GitIdentifier}m}{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple problems in this code:

We do not want to escape any character, if used as an input and, as @David Carlisle mentioned, the input for `lsinputlistings` needs to be expanded.
The optional structure is, as @egreg mentioned, better delegated to `xparse`.
For getting an optional command I used the `DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` from (i think) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50784/189114).

Combining these facts we get a function definition of the macro and prequisites as follows:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501640/shellescape-macro-nested-in-another-macro?noredirect=1#comment1266953_501640
\usepackage{xparse}

% this is set as fallback
\NewDocumentCommand{\GitRemote}{}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\GitIdentifier}{}{master}


\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GitCheckout} {O{\GitIdentifier} O{\GitRemote} m} {%
|"git archive --remote=#2 #1 #3 2>/dev/null | tar --extract --file - --to-stdout"
}
```

Comment: Still `\ProvideDocumentCommand` is very strange. You *don't* want that `\GitIdentifier` does something completely unexpected, do you? So you want to be informed that `\NewDocumentCommand` fails and change the name, rather than having mysterious troubles along the way.

Comment: I remember now, why I have this: 
I had a weird bug with this always complaining na dfixed it by using provide, but i just sourced the file multiple times;
will adopt your change