# Input a file from the web via Overleaf

Tags: input, overleaf, external-files

I want to include some code in a document, but it would be very nice if that code would automatically update whenever it was updated on GitHub.

Looks like I can include text from a remote file as described here:

[Is it possible to input a file from the web](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249567/is-it-possible-to-input-a-file-from-the-web)

Is it possible to do something similar using Overleaf?

Comment: This is a great question for Overleaf support (disclosure: I work for Overleaf support). Short answer: yes, but not exactly: New File > From External URL allows you to pull a file into the project from a source like Github. It is not fetched at compile time, and needs to be manually refreshed. Contact Overleaf support for more info. :)